# Wordpress 3.9.2 and MYSQLI

Tags: php, wordpress, select, mysqli, database-connection

I have since update my server to the latest PHP version and I am running Wordpress 3.9.2 Because of the updates Wordpress now uses MYSQLI instead of MYSQL and I have some custom data connections running which will of course not work now.

I have changed from MYSQL to MSQLI functions, but of course they will not run correctly unless i use the database connection suffix

Example

```
$results = $wpdb->query("SELECT County FROM counties");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row["County"]. "<br>';
}  
$results->free();
```

Though I know there are results, it produces none and i am thinking I have the wrong connection name wpdb

Does anyone know what the DB connection name is in wordpress

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by 'wordpress connection name', but you should try using Wpdb class to run all your queries, thus delegating to the wp engine the problem of dealing with the db.

Comment: Hi I have tried using $wpdb in the query statement but to no avail What i am trying to get is the name of the connection string to the database eg $wpdb=new msqli (connection details)

Comment: added my query string above

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT County FROM counties");
foreach ($results as $row) {
echo $row->County;
}
```